# Remove \r character from the middle of file name

Tags: python, ubuntu, replace, filenames

I have files on the linux server and their file names are broken because of the middle \r character. I couldn't download those files by using WinScp or Filezilla on windows.

Moreover I couldn't rename or process them properly in python.
On command

```
files = os.listdir("2014/")
```

I got this list set.

```
['16963_6_iris2570_20150110_052515\r_172518.gpx', '29174_3_Sunnam0223_20150114_0                                                                                                                                                             10833\r_130835.gpx', '35767_3_samsi2_20150117_035045\r_155047.gpx', '36581_4_kix                                                                                                                                                             ing_20150117_045424\r_165425.gpx', '33383_4_rnrghk10kr_20150117_101618\r_101619.                                                                                                                                                             gpx']
```

On command:

```
file1 = files[0]
```

output: `_172518.gpxs2570_20150110_052515`

Then I try to replace \r

```
file2 = files[0].replace('\r', '')
```

output: `16963_6_iris2570_20150110_052515_172518.gpx`

That's good but when I try to rename:

```
os.rename("2014/"+file1, "2014/"+file2)
f = open(file2, "r")
data = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    f = open(file2, "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '29174_3_Sunnam0223_20150114_010833_130835.gpx'
```

Comment: I think I should use something else instead of os.dirlist which will ignore \r in the filename?

Comment: you should have opened `"2014/" + file2`

Comment: Have you considered opening `"2014/" + file2` instead of `file2`?

Comment: Right, I missed the folder, now it works

Comment: By the way, the `files[0]` appeared incomplete because when you printed it the `\r` character caused the early characters int he filename to be overprinted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
f = open("2014/"+file2, "r")
```

In your example code above, you included the 2014 folder name in your rename, but not in your open call.